# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. flutter android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, exception, gradle

I just intalled android studio and created a new project for flutter, I'm trying to run the default code but it gives me this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find bundletool-1.8.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.2/bundletool-1.8.2.jar
   > Could not find transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
   > Could not find core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.8-alpha07).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.8-alpha07/core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I can open those links in my browser btw but I don't know what is the problem here.

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }



    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

if more information is needed let me know. thanks

I searched for a few hours and tried all solutions given but nothing worked.